# Google Chrome V-62 Beta not showing HTTPS Warning

Tags: google-chrome

Google-Chrome version 62, to be released October 17th 2017, will display a  "Not Secure" warning before the URL if the page is HTTP and contains a form. This message will display once the user starts typing in a form field.

I will be making the changes, this week, to make my site fully HTTPS.

I downloaded the Beta version of Chrome and installed it on my computer. Note as of August 2017 you can now run multiple versions of Chrome (Live/Beta/Dev/Canary) on the same computer computer without issues.

I then tested the Chrome 62 Beta version for Windows 62-bit. In my test I do not get the "Not Secure" message when typing in a form on an HTTP page. This message should also display on any HTTP when in Incognito mode. Again I do not get the message when testing that out either.

Question: Why do I not get the "Not Secure" message when using the Beta version on Chrome 62? Has anyone else noticed this, or is it me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

62 is now in stable channel, the release notes briefly mention the new non-SSL warnings, and yet still the default for me is to not show the message. (Unless I manually change the flag for it in chrome://flags)

The answer here is Chrome Field Trials:

> Where possible, Chrome rolls out new features dynamically using the Field Trials platform. You can think of Field Trials as a set of server-controlled flags that allow Google to change Chrome’s behavior dynamically, at runtime, without shipping a new version.
>
> After a feature has proven itself via experiments, it’s ready to roll out to users in the Stable channel. Unfortunately, pre-release channels don’t get coverage nearly as broad as we’d like, so we have to take care when a feature is first rolled out to Stable. By using a field trial, we can enable the new feature for a huge number of Stable users while still keeping it at a low percentage of the Stable user base (e.g. 1% of a billion installs == 10 million clients). We keep an eagle eye on telemetry and user-feedback reports to spot any unexpected problems, and assuming we don’t find any, we can quickly ramp up the new feature rollout to 100% of users. If we discover the feature wasn’t fit to ship for whatever reason (e.g. introduces some serious bug), we can dial it back to 0% until a fix can be created.

Source: https://textslashplain.com/2017/10/18/chrome-field-trials/

For practical steps on how to address this, have a look at https://www.troyhunt.com/the-6-step-happy-path-to-https/ (Including #6 at the end on CSP reports, which I've used myself to assist in switching over...)

Answer (score 3):

To see this new warning in action, you will need to enable the corresponding option in the Chrome hidden settings.

- Open this URL in your Chrome to see the list of Chrome hidden
  settings: **chrome://flags/#mark-non-secure-as** . You will see the "Mark
  non-secure origins as non-secure" line in the settings. It will have
  "default" option chosen
- Switch to the "Warn on HTTP while in Incognito mode or after editing 
  forms" option in the drop-down
- Save and relaunch Chrome

It seems like the default value for this option doesn't imply any warning now, but they will change it when it's in the stable branch. I am not sure why it is not enabled in beta though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Chrome team is defering this change.
I don't think they'll change default behaviour in stable versione before doing so in dev / beta channel.

Comment: Google Chrome 62.0.3202.62 is now out and installed on my Windows 7 & 10 Desktops. This change has not been implemented. This article confirms it. https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/18/google-chrome-62-stable-is-out/

Comment: Those aren't the official release notes. These are: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/nic62#https See my answer to this question for the reason it hasn't rolled out to everyone yet.